# What would happen if you tried to start an engine with the cam gears meshed

Tags: engine-theory, camshaft, valve-timing

What would happen in the case that someone tried to start an engine like this:
[image: picture of engine with valve cover removed, cam gears exposed and meshed to each other with timing chain installed]
My guess would be, if the starter has enough torque to overcome the strength of the cam gear teeth, it'd wreck the cam gears, valves, etc. or if it doesn't, nothing would happen but some buzzing and heat from the starter motor.

Comment: My guess is that the starter would not be able to overcome it.  However, it might stress the timing chain a bit.